# Check dom element if it has property

Tags: javascript

I have this element:

```
<div class="column" style="background: green;" used="used"></div>
```

How can I check if the div has the 'used' property = 'used'?

I am asking how to do this in javascript not in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by using [`getAttribute(attributeName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function,

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".colum[user]");
var hasUsed = elem.getAttribute("used") == "used";

console.log(hasUsed); //  true/false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `hasAttribute`

```
document.getElementById("divid").hasAttribute("used");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do checking like this:

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName("column")[0].getAttribute("used")=="used"){
    alert('it has the "used" property.')
}
```

```html
<div class="column" style="background: green;" used="used"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[HTML DOM hasAttribute() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp)

```
var elemArr = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
for(i = 0; i < elemArr.length; i++){
   if (elem[i].hasAttribute("used")){
      alert('it has the "used" property.');
   }
}
```

remember you are dealing with a class and could be present in more than one element...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate only div elements with getElementByTagName

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        if(divs[i].getAttribute("used") == "used"){
            alert(divs[i].id);
        }
    }
```